# Mysql Update +1 not working on live server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Am using my local machine to develop my websites. I am currently working on a script o jail  content **scrapers** and ban them later on.

I am dealing with the follow 'strange' mysql update situation.

By trying to update the counter to set the current int + 1, It wont happen and the same records is inserted as a new record.

When I run the exactly same query on my local machine (even with multiply fast requests) It count's like it supposed to be.

Could it be the **scraper** with same ip is requesting pages faster than mySQL can write away the queries so they will be in a kind of queue?

Some one some good advice to treat this well?

Some more code:

```
// Check if ip exists
        $sql = $this->dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE ipv4 = '$this->ipv4'");
        $sql->execute();
        
        $data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        
        if ($data) {
            // Update counter ip
            $sql = $this->dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE $this->table SET counter = counter+1 WHERE ipv4 = '$data->ipv4'");
            $sql->execute();
            
        } else {
            
            // Insert new ip
            $ip2long = ip2long($this->ip);
            $sql = $this->dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table (ip, ipv4, referer, useragent) VALUES ('$ip2long', '$this->ip', '$this->referer', '$this->userAgent')");
            $sql->execute();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter+1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query instead.